# Events are not getting fired on floating container or component in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, components, onclicklistener, floating

I have added a float container and inside it i have added a component,as shown below,

```
var me = this;
var lastTab = me.getLastTabInTabPanel();
var iconContainer = me.down('#iconContainer');
if (iconContainer == null) {
    iconContainer = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
        id: 'iconContainer',
        floating: true,
        shadow: false,
        listeners: {
            click: this.valIconClicked,
            scope: this
        },
        style: 'margin-left:280px;',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'component',
                id: 'valIcon',
                cls: 'valuation-tool-specview',
                height: 33,
                width: 26,
                listeners: {
                    click: this.valIconClicked,
                    scope: this
                }
            }
        ]
    });
}
iconContainer.showBy(lastTab, 'tl-tr');//, [-2, 0]
```

click event is not getting fired, did i miss anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Components don't have a click event. But you can attach a listener to their element's click like this:

```
listeners: {
    click: {
        element: 'el',
        scope: this,
        fn: this.valIconClicked
   }
}
```